# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: No valid combination of account information found

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues, azure-functions-runtime

I am using Azure Functions Preview and want to add a QueueTrigerFunction.

The function is defined as such:

```
[FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]        
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("testqueue1", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

with the local.settings.json:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=test1storage;AccountKey=XXXXX==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net/;",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  }
}
```

When I start up the VS Debugger, I get the following error message:

> [8/5/2017 1:07:56 AM] Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: No valid combination of
>   account information found.

What am I missing? Is there some additional settings in Azure I need to check to make sure this scenario is correctly configured?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What am I missing? Is there some additional settings in Azure I need to check to make sure this scenario is correctly configured?

I can reproduce the issue that you mentioned with you supplied AzureWebJobsStorage connection string format. Please have a try to remove `EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net/;` from the connection string. Then it works correctly on my side.

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountname;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You saved me hours.  Why is this still an issue?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.  The connection string in the Azure Portal that i copy/pasted, included 'EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net' at the end of the string.  When i used this, i got the same error as above.  When i simply removed this part of the connection string i was able to connect successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where it failed to connect.

I was running the function locally on a unix system and instead of using the local settings I used a straight forward environment variable.

Turned out that when declaring the variable it should be quoted:

export AzureWebJobsStorage="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;Accoun..." and that solved the problem, guessing some characters are treated incorrectly otherwise